# React optimization: what is the goal of applying useMemo to useState return values?

Tags: reactjs, use-state, react-context, react-usememo

In [this article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react) on state management with context API, the author applies useMemo to useState return values this way:

```
function CountProvider(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const value = React.useMemo(() => [count, setCount], [count])
  return <CountContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />
}
```

I am not sure to understand the goal of this optimization:

- 1/ is it to prevent re-rendering in case any of the *props* change,
- 2/ or can *setCount* itself change spuriously?

If it is for 1/, isn't it equivalent to the following code?
(because: what props other than *children* would we want to pass to the context provider? and if *children* change, a re-render is desirable)

```
function CountProvider({children}) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  return (
    <CountContext.Provider value={[count, setCount]}>
      {children}
    </CountContext.Provider>
  );
}
```